# If $|A|\ge2$ and $\alpha:A\to A$ satisfies $\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha$ for all $\beta:A\to A$, prove that $\alpha=1_A$.

Tags: functions

This question is in the first chapter of my abstract algebra textbook. Neither the textbook or the solution manual give an answer, so I assume it's fairly straightforward, and I'm just missing something obvious. I've tried directly proving it as well as trying to prove the contrapositive, but haven't been successful. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try the case $|A|=2$ first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\alpha \neq \operatorname{id}_A$, i.e. there exists $x,y \in A$ such that $\alpha(x) = y$ with $x \neq y$. Define $\beta : A \to A$ by
$$\beta(z) = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if } z = x \text{ or } z = y \\
z & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Then $\beta(\alpha(x)) = \beta(y) = x$, while $\alpha(\beta(x)) = \alpha(x) = y \neq x$, so $\alpha\beta \neq \beta\alpha$. By considering the contrapositive, if $\alpha\beta = \beta\alpha$ for all $\beta$, then $\alpha = \operatorname{id}_A$.